# Keep getting "Cannot be resolved into a Type" errors after adding secondary Project to Build path

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, buildpath

I'm using Eclipse IDE.

I keep getting the same error: "Cannot Resolve *whateverClass* to a Type"

Here's my code:
https://github.com/devcarokp/JEE.git

So I have:

- hsports-catalog-CDI --> my main EAR project for deployment

It contains: hsports-catalog-ejb and hsports-catalog-jsf-CDI.

- hsports-catalog-ejb --> EJB project (jar in the EAR)
- hsports-catalog-jsf-CDI --> Web project (war in the EAR)

So I have tried adding hsports-catalog-ejb to hsports-catalog-jsf-CDI's Java Build Path as a Project, as a referenced source folder, etc... but I still can't get access to its classes.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong anymore.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with your project configuration. Unfortunately, in the linked Git repository the `.project`, `.classpath` files and the `.settings`  folder which are intended to be shared are missing. Please also tell whether _"Cannot Resolve whateverClass to a Type"_ are the only errors you get. Please also tell the exact error message instead of _"whateverClass"_ (I doubt you get this for any class).

Comment: Hello howlger, thanks for replying, I had not noticed the missing files. I did a little workaround, please check the repo again. In this case, the error "CatalogItem cannot be resolved to a type" presents itself in CatalogItemDeleteBean.java and the error "CatalogLocal cannot be resolved to a type" in CatalogItemFormBean.java. I'm very inclined towards thinking it must be a configuration error, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.